# Why is my iOS Development Certificate Team ID different from my real Team ID?

Tags: xcode, keychain, development

When I create an iOS Development Certificate using Xcode or the manual CSR process, the Team ID is something like (for e.g.) `EK1H65HGFB`, whereas my Team ID according to the Apple website is actually `ECTE57HE5G`. Creating a Distribution Certificate in Xcode works just fine and produces a certificate with a correct Team ID.

This discrepancy causes provisioning profiles to break because they expect a Development Certificate with my real Team ID.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this? Is this a problem with my Xcode configuration? (I have removed all it's settings and reinstalled it though.)

Comment: Did you find the reason for the differences in Team IDs? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: I got an email from Apple Technical Developer Support explaining the whole thing. I'll answer my own question later.

Answer (score 2):

I've since had communication with the Apple Developer Program Support and they've sent me an email clarifying the team IDs.
This is what they wrote:

> Please note that I can confirm that the ID assigned to the IOS Development Certificate is a random one and is not the Team ID, therefore it is expected behavior. The ID assigned to the IOS Distribution Certificate would match the TID.

It seems the TeamID of the Development Certificate is in fact random. I wasn't able to do purchases in my app because of a bug and not this error.